# Why is my do-while loop not breaking when I enter a number that is accepted?

Tags: c++

Whether I enter accepted or non-accepted values, the loop keeps running.

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <vector>
        using namespace std;

        int main(){
          int size;
          bool accepted = ((size == 0) || (size == 3) || (size == 4) || (size == 5));
          /************************************************************************/
          do {
            cout << "Enter number of digits in code (3, 4 or 5): " << flush;
            cin >> size;
          } while (!accepted);
          /************************************************************************/
          //static_cast<const int>(size);
          cout << size;
          return 0;
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of `size` when that `bool accepted = ` line is executed?  C++ runs a program top down.

Answer (score 1):

The bool is not updated every iteration. Only at the start. To make the logic work you need to put

```
accepted = ((size == 0) || (size == 3) || (size == 4) || (size == 5));
```

inside of the loop.

```
        int main(){
          int size;
          bool accepted;
          /************************************************************************/
          do {
            cout << "Enter number of digits in code (3, 4 or 5): " << flush;
            cin >> size;
            accepted = ((size == 0) || (size == 3) || (size == 4) || (size == 5));
          } while (!accepted);
          /************************************************************************/
          //static_cast<const int>(size);
          cout << size;
          return 0;
        }
```